# sqlachlemy multiple counts in a module

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to get a count of rows in an sqlalchemy database, for each unique entry in a column, while simultaneously filtering for another two columns.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class FPTP(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    candid = db.Column(db.String(40), index=True, unique=False)
    riding = db.Column(db.String(50), index=True, unique=False)
    election = db.Column(db.String(30), index=True, unique=False)

    def results(self, riding, election):
        result = self.query(func.count(self.candid), self.candid).\
                 filter(and_(self.election==election, self.riding==riding)).\
                 group_by(self.candid)
        return result
```

The documentation makes `func.count` an argument of `query`, and so does a tutorial, and some of the other answers here:
[count unique rows in sql-alchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31863255/count-unique-rows-in-sql-alchemy), [SQLAlchemy func.count with filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34446725/sqlalchemy-func-count-with-filter).

But when I do that I get:`TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable`.  And another answer here explained that `query` is an instance and not a class with it's own functions, which was helpful.  But the documentation and the tutorial make `func.count` called by `query`.

I also see examples are in a "session": [Group by & count function in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1052148/group-by-count-function-in-sqlalchemy).  I want this in a module, not in an interpreter.  So building a shell, making a session, and binding an engine is not a solution I am looking for.

I see other answers here (like: [Define name for column func.count in sqlalchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497179/define-name-for-column-func-count-in-sqlalchemy)), but that's about naming the columns and getting the count for a unique occurrence.  I want to do it more pythonic than here: [TypeError: 'BaseQuery' object is not callable Flask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058438/typeerror-basequery-object-is-not-callable-flask).

I want to call this function:

```
results = FPTP.results("Some Riding", "Election")
```

and get a count of all occurrences like what is given on page 21 of the documentation:

```
[(1, 'ed'), (1, 'fred'), (1, 'mary'), (1, 'wendy')]
```

after filtering by two other columns.

Comment: try something like http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.object_session

Comment: @Shiva, that uses a session.  When I add to the database, I use `db.session.add(something)` and `db.session.commit()`.  How is the information contained in your link different than what I have with `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`?  Thanks.

Comment: you are getting error in this place self.query(

Comment: ... but `self.query.filter(something).all()` works.  The error is actually stating that `query` is not callable.  So query() gives the error.